# Capturing the undo/redo Unity shortcut when a custom EditorWindow has focus

Tags: unity, c#

I'm working on an editor tool which can have multiple windows to edit different files at the same time. I'd like to implement my own undo/redo functionality, independent for each window, and independent from the rest of Unity.

However, I can't find a way to stop Unity from capturing the undo/redo shortcut; it seems like it will always get it and then call its [Undo API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Undo.html) which will affect the Scene and whatnot.

Is it possible for my `EditorWindow` to tell Unity not to undo/redo things if it has focus?